# Reference and code for community discovery algorithms in multigraphs

Tags: algorithms, reference-request, clustering

In order to group unstructured or sem-structured texts for a timeline construction approach, I consider several types of correlations among such texts. These different correlations induce a weighted [multigraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multigraph), where the texts act as nodes. All edges have a normalized weight between $0$ and $1$.

I wonder what algorithms exist to find community structures within such multigraphs. The problem of community discovery in static and even dynamic graphs without multiple edges between nodes is well-studied. See e.g. [this article](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4419-8462-3_4) and [this one](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/3172867?casa_token=-H2qaHBiYXkAAAAA:VFfZxKMPvqrOECbFMexKp44h-_CPfMAV_ShNOpUrI_ZzckMlabo2fOE-6o9LmGZM-sLkoEpHVjPt87c) for accounts on these respective subjects.

However, it appears that the community discovery problem on multigraphs has been studied considerably less extensively. I've found a few relevant articles on the topic, including [this 2012 paper](https://aclanthology.org/P13-3012/) by Martschat, and [this article](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/5360349?casa_token=6p4vonLbkqQAAAAA:0nXzDmGAumfN4t8wUDsHiNkPd1w0zrcr1ExbqiAjC33v-Dglt2qCbhGks_RJG-KILReGLZuWhv0l) by Tang et al. (2009) considers community discovery in multiple graphs with the same nodes.

**Question**: are there more recent community discovery algorithms for multigraphs that are described in the scientific literature, and preferably also include open-source code that allows one to implement the algorithm on a data set?

*Note*: I've asked more or less the [same question](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/41838/algorithms-for-community-discovery-in-multigraphs) about a week ago on Artificial Intelligence SE. It hasn't received a lot of attention over there.

Comment: Why multigraphs rather than directed graphs? Couldn't you accumulate weights or keep sets of weights as labels?

Comment: @Kai The idea behind this approach is that the edges between the nodes represent different types of correlations between the texts. Adding these up would be possible, but it would lose important information. For instance, if the actoral coherence between two texts is $1$ while the topical coherence is $0$, adding the coherences up would yield the same type of connection between two texts where the actoral coherence is $0$ and the topical coherence is $1$. I therefore prefer to find methods for community discover that keep the multigraph structure intact.